# React navigation back button shows navigator name instead of screen name

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Pasting the entire code would be very long, so I created a snack for this: https://snack.expo.dev/@kickbk/fd9160

If you click the bottom tabs on **"Account" -> "Go To Profile" -> "Go To Auth Navigator"**, you will then notice the back button shows **"< Root"**, but I expect it to show the last screen that we navigated from (Profile).

How do I get the back button to show the screen title that navigated into it?
I **do not** want to place the Authentication navigator screens inside the root navigator. They need to stay inside Authentication navigator.